# move an object along another creating a animating in tween.js

Tags: javascript, animation, tween.js

I have an object that is a line. I would like to make an animation with an object that will move all vertices of the line, it can be a sphere. for that I will use tween.js. my problem is that I can not achieve all its vertices animation. how I can do to make the animation is displayed from the start point to the end ?. I have this code:

[image]

```
//myline.geometry.vertices  -> array with vertices of the line (1000 vertices for example)
//myline.geometry.vertices[0]=>x:1,y:2:z:0;
//myline.geometry.vertices[1]=>x:3,y:5:z:0;
//...
new TWEEN.Tween( mysphere.position ).to( { x: myline.geometry.vertices[0].x, y: myline.geometry.vertices[0].y, z: myline.geometry.vertices[0].z }, 9000 ).to( { x: myline.geometry.vertices[1].x, y: myline.geometry.vertices[1].y, z: myline.geometry.vertices[1].z }, 9000 ).delay(2000).start();
```

I use the ".to" method and works well, if I put the vertices to which I want to move. but if I have 1000 vertices, I would have to put them all. What can I do?. . I need to move a sphere along a line .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create a loop that specifies the transition for each vertex. You also need to set the position of the sphere to the previous vertex, otherwise the position is cached and each tween will begin at the sphere's position prior to the execution of the loop. Additionally, since these tweens are executing so quickly inside the loop, you need to specify a delay so the transition can begin at the correct time.

```
// Get the vertices for each line.
var vertices = line.geometry.vertices;
// Specify the duration for each tween.
var duration = 500;
// Iterate through each vertex in the line, starting at 1.
for (var i = 1, len = vertices.length; i < len; i++) {
    // Set the position of the sphere to the previous vertex.
    sphere.position.copy(vertices[i - 1]);
    // Create the tween from the current sphere position to the current vertex.
    new TWEEN.Tween(sphere.position).to(vertices[i], duration).delay(i * duration).start();
}
```

Comment: oh very interesting, thank you very much !. I have a question. I would have to do to put a number of spheres on the line and create an animation ?.I want to move several areas along the line and the same distance.  http://i.imgur.com/nqtGzjn.png

Comment: What happens when the nth sphere reaches the end of the line? Does a new one spawn at the beginning of the line? Seems like a trickier problem, and at the very least you would need to track when the nth sphere is at the last vertex and decide what to do from there (reverse the animation, remove it, etc). You also need to determine whether the spheres are on each vertex at the beginning of the animation or if you begin with one sphere, it tweens to the next vertex and another sphere is created at the first vertex and repeat the process.

Comment: I have thought of doing so. when the first sphere, end  the animation, the animation will be  infinity. restarts from the vertex 0, until the last vertex. I want,all spheres have an animation as I showed in the picture ..

Comment: I do not know what to do, to synchronize animation as I said. n number of spheres doing what I want.

Comment: how I can do to make the animation is infinite ?. I want when finished start again from the first vertex.